# Is there a way to change an existing map from Default to Large biomes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm OK with there being 'unnatural' stuff at the borders of the 1.2.5 map and the 1.3.1 map, but I'd like all the newly generated areas to be LARGE BIOME. I am using Bukkit, is it as simple as changing the server.properties file or is there more going on here?

Answer (score 3):

First a quick note, **This will not affect any chunks that are already generated.**  Only the ones generated after changing to LARGE BIOMES.

1. Download [NBTedit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/) and then extract and run it.
2. Click "Open" and navigate to your server directory.
3. Find your world folder and open the file "level.dat" inside of it.
4. Expand the folder you are presented with in NBTedit.
5. Find the field "generatorName" and double-click it.
6. Change the value from "default" to "largeBiomes" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Now click "Save".
8. You can now close NBTedit and enjoy your larger biomes.

Comment: Thank ye, I will give this a try.

Comment: Has this worked?  If so, please mark this as the chosen answer.

Comment: I haven't tried it as the whole thing was running on a CentOS server that I access entirely using command line. We ended up starting a fresh map, so I have no idea if this works or not.